# Is it possible to create a regex to match a line that contains one word but not another?

Tags: regex

[Similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2953039/regular-expression-for-a-string-containing-one-word-but-not-another) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/406230/regular-expression-to-match-string-not-containing-a-word) [have](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7839852/regex-find-one-word-but-not-another) [been](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9912914/regular-expression-searching-matching-one-word-but-not-another) asked, but none answer this specific question.

Given this representative text:

```
foo
bar
foo bar
bar foo
foo bar foo
bar foo bar
```

Is it possible to use regular expressions to match only lines that do contain the word `foo` but don't contain the word `bar`?

If this desired regular expression was run on the above text, it would only result in:

```
foo
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here is a fairly straightforward way to do this:

```
^(?!.*\bbar\b).*\bfoo\b.*
```

Explanation:

```
^               # starting at beginning of the string
(?!             # fail if (negative lookahead)
   .*\bbar\b      # the word 'bar' exists anywhere in the string 
)               # end negative lookahead
.*\bfoo\b.*     # match the line with the word 'foo' anywhere in the string
```

Rubular: http://www.rubular.com/r/pLeqGQUXbj

`\b` in regex is a [word boundary](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html).

Vim version:

```
^\(.*\<bar\>\)\@!.*\<foo\>.*
```

Comment: Anybody want to be my hero and present this regex in a form that `vim` accepts?

Comment: @CoryKlein - Edited my answer with a Vim version.

Comment: Thank YOU! F.J. you are my hero!

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  Use lookarounds.

```
/^.*(?<!\bbar\b.*)\bfoo\b(?!.*\bar\b).*$/
```